# Custom Map using ibeacon technology swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

i have started working on an application where i will be using ibeacons to fetch the distance and show the distance between your iphone device and beacons around the iphone device. i gone through lots of stuff about beacons and some SDK which i can use to make an application like Estimote, Eddystone, ibeacons .

Only part i am not able to understand where i want to add an custom map in it . how i can achieve that . so that it can link to beacons and show the location of the beacon in a map format .

this question might be naive but i am stuck and unable to understand . any help would be appreciated

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of map SDKs you can use on iOS including Apple's MapKit and [Google Maps for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro).  You can also simply draw your own map as a SVG image (a vector scalable format allow you to zoom in and out without losing resolution.)  You can then record in your app the latitude and longitude of the beacon, and when detected, center the map to that latitude and longitude perhaps with a blue dot at the center.

Comment: thank you for your response . so i have to check the beacons latitude and longitude and keep it is the same latitude and longitude keep in the map this will work right @davidgyoung

Comment: this method [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/ios-navigation-sdk/) i can use it with estimote